# How to create a channel of receive-only channels?

Tags: go, channel

I want to create a channel from which someone can only pull receive-only channels, for instance:

```
c := make(chan <-chan int)
```

However, I can't read from this channel:

```
invalid operation: <-c (receive from send-only type chan<- chan int)
```

([Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/_LgvgCsY2nQ)) From the error message, it's clear that my syntax `chan <-chan` is interpreted as `chan<- chan`, i.e. a send-only channel of channels. Running `gofmt` even changes the code to reflect this.

So how do I denote the channel type I want?

Comment: Except for the case where the only operation on the cannel is a `close` you do _not_ want to `make` a receive only channel as nobody would be able to send.

Comment: @Volker, `close` is a send operation, you can’t close a read only channel either. The only thing it can do is block indefinitely on a receive.

Comment: @Volker I'm not `make`ing a receive-only channel. I'm `make`ing a regular send-receive channel. Then I'm inserting receive-only channels into it, but those receive-only channels are of course "upcasted" from regular send-receive channels. Some other goroutine is holding the sending end of those channels.

Comment: @JimB Yes, sorry. You do not want to make a **unidirectional** channel.

Comment: @Thomas While a chan-of-chan might be useful the question is of basically no relevance.

Comment: @Volker It was not obvious to me how to write this syntax. I could not find any information about how to do it, and `gofmt` kept "correcting" my code to something different from what I intended. Even when I realized that `gofmt` was just rewriting the code to match the compiler's interpretation, I still didn't know how to write this correctly. Hence this self-answered question. It may not be relevant to you, but that doesn't mean it's of "no relevance" to anyone.

Comment: As a hint, when you format this (which you should always be doing), the statement is reformatted to `chan<- chan int` which should be a good indication of how it's being evaluated and if you need parenthesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If something is unclear regarding Go's syntax, the [language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec) should be the first thing to check. Compared to other languages, Go's spec is more readable and shorter.

Exactly this is mentioned in [Spec: Channel types:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Channel_types)

> The `<-` operator associates with the leftmost `chan` possible:
>
> ```
> chan<- chan int    // same as chan<- (chan int)
> chan<- <-chan int  // same as chan<- (<-chan int)
> <-chan <-chan int  // same as <-chan (<-chan int)
> chan (<-chan int)
> ```

The answer is there clear and simple in these few quoted lines.

- The **reason** for what you experience: the `<-` operator associates with the leftmost `chan` possible.
- The **meaning** of what you've tried: `chan<- chan int` is the same as `chan<- (chan int)`
- The **solution** to what you want to achieve (the last line): `chan (<-chan int)`

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simple: add parentheses.

```
c := make(chan (<-chan int))
```

An alternative, which might be more readable in some situations, would be to create a new type for the inner channel:

```
type ReceiveOnlyIntChan <-chan int
c := make(chan ReceiveOnlyIntChan)
```

Comment: Bad use of type alias. A simple named type would do.

Comment: I think a type alias might have its uses (e.g. if the caller just wants a `<-chan int` and not bother with your internal types), but OK, I'll change it.